# How can I embed my javascript and PHP code for language translation and make a Shopify app?

Tags: javascript, php, shopify, google-translate

I am making app that converts the language of Shopify pages at the front-end site with the browser specific location, During with this I have tried a lot but not getting actual what I want. I have also seen the Shopify discussion forum for api request, but I have read that Shopify doesn't allow the update Shopify data threw api request. So how it can be possible to change the language at front-end in browser location country specific.

I have created the partner account, app name, app secret key for creating an app. But problem is that where to start and embed my javascript and PHP code with Shopify.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Google Auto Translation API..?

Comment: I am using it but I want little bit changes in that the default language with browser location specific language, means if the shopify store is open to the Africaans ip then the front-end will change in to the Africaans language.